# sum record by the acceptance condition in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table such as;

```
id    accepted    date
----------------------------------
1        0     2016-01-05 14:58:31 
2        0     2016-01-07 14:58:31
3        1     2016-01-11 14:58:31
4        0     2016-01-12 14:58:31
4        2     2016-01-12 14:58:31
....
```

accepted value of 0 means the recording waiting, accepted value of 1 means the recording not accepted and accepted value of 2 means the recording accepted.

I want to sum of each accept condition by date, I try this code;

```
SELECT 
  SELECT SUM(IF (t2.accepted = 0, 1, 0)) 
  FROM table as t2 WHERE t2.date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND t2.date <= '2016-01-22 23:59:59') as waiting, 
  (SELECT SUM(IF (t3.accepted = 1, 1, 0))
  FROM table as t3 WHERE t3.date >= '2016-01-15 00:00:00' AND t3.date <= '2016-01-22 23:59:59') as not_accepted, 
  (SELECT SUM(IF (t4.accepted = 2, 1, 0)) 
  FROM table as t4 WHERE t4.date >= '2016-01-15 00:00:00' AND t4.date <= '2016-01-22 23:59:59') as accepted 
FROM table AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.accepted
```

Output is;

```
waiting    not_accepted     accepted
------------------------------------
21             152             1
21             152             1
21             152             1
```

the result is correct, but the same result shows 3 times? How can I get in one line?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: And this query would produce a syntax error, so you're not quite telling us the truth

Comment: Id field is primary key. main question that more complex than this question   but I asked a little simplify :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(accepted = 0) zero
     , SUM(accepted = 1) one
     , SUM(accepted = 2) two 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-22 23:59:59';
```

Comment: You now better than to just post an answer, please elaborate people are looking up to you

Comment: @davejal I'm happy for you to elaborate on my behalf.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks. This answer was the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

3 rows because accepted has 3 different values 0, 1, 2

You can just remove the `FROM table AS t1  GROUP BY t1.accepted` because t1 is not used in the subqueries